# Question "bumping" - is it ok?

Tags: discussion

Situation: I've got an answer out there (link withheld for obvious reasons) that just needs *one more* competitive vote to get the Populist gold badge.

Is it considered bad practice to edit or comment on an old post just to bring it back to the top of the "Active" list so people see it?

Comment: What is the question?  There are new people (like me) on the site that may have something to add to it.

Comment: He's not mentioning because it's even worse practice to link your question in meta begging for more attention...

Comment: You did it!  Congratulations!

Comment: @Kalamane Thanks. I didn't even need to bump it :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are there absolutely no improvements you could make to your answer, the question, or any other post? Arbitrary bumping is frowned on (and can attract downvotes). Improving posts (along with some patience) is encouraged.

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

> First, make sure you've asked a good question. To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

See this related MSO question: [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Yes, I suppose the whole purpose behind the rep/badge system is to encourage users to increase the quality of the site content. Good point.

Comment: @dpatchery You grok it.

Answer (score 6):

Don't ask, don't tell. Just don't make it a habit.

Comment: +1 for honesty...

Comment: There's the complicated answer and then there's the true answer